# How to generate a pulse wave in MATLAB for a given frequency

Tags: matlab

How can I generate a pulse wave, with a frequency of 100 kHz, while the pulse is 'on' for 5 nano seconds, and 'off' for 6 micro seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm... let's see. On for 5 nsec and off for 6 usec is not 100kHz. How long is the wave? Let's say you want it to be T seconds long, with an 'on' interval defined as on, and an  cycle of cyc then:

```
fs = 2.0000e+09; % sampling rate; this will give you ~10 samples per 5 nsec pulse
on = 5e-9; % interval for pulse-on (5nsec for you)
cyc = 6e-6 % cycle (6usec for you)

% time base: 
t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs; 
% the signal: 
w = mod(t/cyc,1)<=on/cyc;
```

modulo cyc sets your cycle at cyc sec; when the signal is <= on/cyc is where in the cycle the pulse should be on.

to verify:

```
figure,
plot(t, w);
```